# How to select a parent element without any class or id using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<div>
<label for="fsc_name1">Name:<span class="required"> *</span></label>
</div>

<div>
<input style="text-align:left; margin:0;" type="text" id="fsc_name1" name="fsc_name" value=""  size="60">
</div>
```

It's a piece of a contact form and I need to be able to hide some of it's elements if a specific element is selected. So lets say I want to hide the two divs above. There's no id or class and I can't give them any. All I have is unique values "for="fsc_name1"" (`<label>`) and "id="fsc_name1"" (`<input>`)

Comment: Your question is a little bit vague. Which element are you selecting, and which would you like to hide?

Comment: It's really worth your time to read the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It takes about 45 minutes to an hour, and it's **hugely** useful.

Comment: Mr. Brownstone - if any of our answers helped you, could you kindly mark one of them as accepted? Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Easy! Just use jQuery `parent()`. See docs: http://api.jquery.com/parent/

```
$('#fsc_name1').parent().hide()
$('label[for="fsc_name1"]').parent().hide()
```

You can also combine your selectors to save space. See docs: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

```
$('#fsc_name1, label[for="fsc_name1"]').parent().hide()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a mix of [atttribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to solve this problem

```
$('label[for="fsc_name1"]').parent().hide()
$('#fsc_name1').parent().hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

For a start, `id="fsc_name1"` **is** a class selector, you can do it via

```
$('#fsc_name1').parent().hide();
```

But, I think for your scenario, you're wanting something like this...

```
// This can be an array of elements
var selector = 'fsc_name1';
$('label[for=' + selector + ']').parent().hide();
$('#' + selector).parent().hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

**No jQuery version:**

```
document.querySelector('[for=fsc_name1]').parentNode.style.display = 'none';
document.querySelector('#fsc_name1').parentNode.style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/31/

```
$('#fsc_name1').closest('div').css('border','1px solid red')
$('#fsc_name1').closest('div').prev('div').css('border','1px solid green')
```

Note: Exactly I am not able to understand your question. So I add the border to the div's in example. If you want to hide, instead off `.css` you add `.hide()`that will hide the div.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: There are other elements in that contact form and I need to build a simple interaction. Say... if a field "I don't have a name" is checked then the divs holding label and an input will disappear. I thing now I know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.parent()` method.

```
$('#fsc_name1').parent().hide();
$('label[for="fsc_name1"]').parent().hide();
```